# Xcode iOS App Loader: ERROR ITMS-4236 "Invalid value [bundle ID] for bundle_version"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting the below error when I deliver my IPA file to Xcode's application loader. 
Anybody experience something similar and know how to resolved?

*ERROR ITMS-4236*:

[image: ERROR ITMS-4236]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ITMS-4236 when uploading build to iTunes because of build version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763222/error-itms-4236-when-uploading-build-to-itunes-because-of-build-version)

Comment: thanks, I resolve this by renaming the bundle version XML file of the project.